# Replace the User GenerateIdentityAsync method in ASP Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm working on my custom implementation of ASP Identity and I have separated my functions on two C# classes projects, one for Entities and one for business logic. I started by copying the default template of Identity for ASP MVC 5 and moving database entities into the Entities project, but then I had to comment the GenerateIdentityAsync method because the UserManager is in another project:

```
public class ApptelinkUser : IdentityUser<long, ApptelinkUserLogin, ApptelinkUserRole, ApptelinkUserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApptelinkUserManager manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

Then I replaced all the calls to this method by calling the CreateIdentityAsync method directly from UserManager, but then I realized the GenerateUserIdentityAsync method was useful for setting up the claims, is there another way to add this method on another project or another workaround for adding the UserClaims?

Comment: The template has that method in the user just for simplicity. It can go anywhere.

Comment: It can be added directly to the SignInManager ?

Comment: You could build the identity before any call to SignInManager